# VisM with VB.net Connection "Server Receive Timed Out"

Tags: vb.net, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I added a VisM control into vb.net via adding a reference to VisM.ocx and adding it in my toolbox as an activeX control.

I added the following code in a button:

```
Try
        'open the connection
        AxVisM1.Connect("CN_IPTCP:127.0.0.1[57772]", "LIVEDATA")


        'do stuff.
        MsgBox("Cache is now active")

        'close the connection
        AxVisM1.DeleteConnection()

    Catch ex As Exception
        'close the connection
        AxVisM1.DeleteConnection()

        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try
```

however when I run the application the connection hangs, followed by a messagebox that says **"Server Receive Timed Out"**.

I have tried turning off my firewall, and even my antivirus. How will I resolve this? Also, is what I am trying an effective way to access GLOBALS variables in VB.net??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VisM, but you using wrong port, and this port only for web, try to change it to 1972, which is used by default. Your server may use another one. Your real port number you can find at System Management Portal on page About (link in the header), and parameter is - Superserver Port.

Comment: You are a Godsend. But can I access GLOBALS with it?

Comment: It is not quite simple, but you can execute any Caché code, simple example [here](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GBCD_basics#GBCD_basics_examples_example2)